# Method taking value as an object not string value

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pass string but it keep passing it as an object. Here is my code:

```
def urljoin(*args):
        return "/".join(map(lambda x: str(x).rstrip('/'), args))
```

When I call it like this:

```
student_name = urljoin('path',self.name)
```

It is creating a url like: path/object at 0x... , how can I make it show the name of the student? Because when I type it in pdb viewer: 
`p self.name` - it shows ken

Comment: What kind of object is `self.name`? Does the class define a `__str__` method?

Comment: @mypetlion - its user input from command line. as: ken for example.